# Replay loop that allows script to be exit at any time

Tags: java, loops, runtime-error, replay

I have an assignment to make a game were the computer generates a number between 1 and 100 and the user tries to guess it. I have it coded I just can't get my replay to work. It gives me an error about index out of range and i have no idea why. I also need the program to be able to exit at any time during the game and call the method exit. I have no clue how to do that. Here is my current code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
/*
Program to let user guess random generated number between 1 and 100 
*/
public class Hilo  
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Random generator = new Random(); // Random generator to generate number 
int computernumber;
int usernumber;
int guesses = 0;
char play;
char playagain;
boolean replay;

public void computerguess()
{
    computernumber = generator.nextInt(100)+1;
}
public void userguess()
{
    if(play == 'y')
    {
    System.out.println("Please guess a number between 1 and 100");
    usernumber = scan.nextInt();
    highorlow();
}
}
public void highorlow()
{
    if(usernumber == computernumber)
    {
    System.out.println("Good Job! Your guessed the correct number!"); // Checks if you guessed the correct number
        guesses = guesses +1; // Adds 1 to guess count
    }
    else
    {
        if(usernumber > computernumber) // Checks if your number is higher than the computers
        {
            System.out.println("Your guessed to high please try again");
                guesses =guesses +1; // Adds 1 to guess count
            userguess(); // Lets user guess again
        }
        else
        {
            if(usernumber < computernumber) // Checks if your number is less than the computers number
            {
                System.out.println("Your guess was to low please try again");
                guesses = guesses +1;// Adds 1 to guess count
                userguess(); // Lets user guess again
            }
        }
    }
}
public void instructions() // Gives instructions on how to play 
{
    System.out.println("To play simply guess a number between 1 and 100. \nThe computer will tell you if you are correct or inncorrect. \n Press y to continue \n Press e at any time to exit");
    play = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
}
public void printscore()
{
    System.out.println("Your took "+guesses+" guesses to get the correct number \n"); // Tells user how many guesses they took 
}
public void replay() // lets user replay game
{
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Y for yes N for no");
    playagain = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);;
    if(playagain =='y')
    {
    replay = true;
    play();
    }
}
public void exit()
{
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing! The number was "+computernumber+"");
}
public void play()
{
    instructions();
    computerguess();
    userguess();
    printscore();
    replay();
    if(replay == true)
    {
    instructions();
    computerguess();
    userguess();
    printscore();
    replay();
}
    else
    {
        if(replay == false)
        {
        System.exit(3);
        }
    }
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Hilo guess = new Hilo();
    guess.play();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably This will do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
/*
Program to let user guess random generated number between 1 and 100 
*/
public class Hilo  
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Random generator = new Random(); // Random generator to generate number 
int computernumber;
int usernumber;
int guesses = 0;
String play;
boolean replay;

public void computerguess()
{
    computernumber = generator.nextInt(100)+1;
}
public void userguess()
{
    if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(play))
    {
    System.out.println("Please guess a number between 1 and 100");
    String input = scan.next();
    if("e".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) exit();
    else usernumber = Integer.parseInt(input);
    highorlow();
    }else if("e".equalsIgnoreCase(play)) exit();
}
public void highorlow()
{
    if(usernumber == computernumber)
    {
    System.out.println("Good Job! Your guessed the correct number!"); // Checks if you guessed the correct number
        guesses = guesses +1; // Adds 1 to guess count
    }
    else
    {
        if(usernumber > computernumber) // Checks if your number is higher than the computers
        {
            System.out.println("Your guessed to high please try again");
                guesses =guesses +1; // Adds 1 to guess count
            userguess(); // Lets user guess again
        }
        else
        {
            if(usernumber < computernumber) // Checks if your number is less than the computers number
            {
                System.out.println("Your guess was to low please try again");
                guesses = guesses +1;// Adds 1 to guess count
                userguess(); // Lets user guess again
            }
        }
    }
}
public void instructions() // Gives instructions on how to play 
{
    System.out.println("To play simply guess a number between 1 and 100. \nThe computer will tell you if you are correct or inncorrect. \n Press y to continue \n Press e at any time to exit");
    play = scan.next();
}
public void printscore()
{
    System.out.println("Your took "+guesses+" guesses to get the correct number \n"); // Tells user how many guesses they took 
}
public void replay() // lets user replay game
{
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Y for yes N for no");
    String input = scan.next();
    if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
    {
    replay = true;
    play();
    }
}
public void exit()
{
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing! The number was "+computernumber+"");
    System.exit(3);
}
public void play()
{
     if(replay == false)
     {
        exit();
     }

    instructions();
    computerguess();
    userguess();
    printscore();
    replay();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Hilo guess = new Hilo();
    guess.replay = true;
    guess.play();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code (I guess this should work - Changes have been commented with a change code : find 'Change' as key word) :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
/*
Program to let user guess random generated number between 1 and 100
*/
public class Hilo
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random generator = new Random(); // Random generator to generate number
    int computernumber;
    int usernumber;
    int guesses = 0;
    char play;
    char playagain;
    //boolean replay;
    //Change Code : Change No. 4 : Start
    boolean replay = true;
    //Change Code : Change No. 4 : End [Refer change No 5. for WHY?]

    public void computerguess()
    {
        computernumber = generator.nextInt(100)+1;
    }
    public void userguess()
    {
        if(play == 'y')
        {

            /*
            Your Code
            usernumber = scan.nextInt();
            highorlow();
            */

            //Change Code : Change No. 1 : Start
            boolean correctNumber = false;

            while (!correctNumber) { // loop is used  to ask user for a correct input

                // this statment moved from above into the loop
                System.out.println("Please guess a number between 1 and 100");


                String inputFromUser = scan.next();
                try{
                    usernumber = Integer.parseInt(inputFromUser);
                    correctNumber = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    if(inputFromUser.equals("e")) { // Then user want to exit the game
                        exit(); // call the exit method
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(" Please input a correct number Please !!! ");
                    }
                }
            }
            //Change Code : Change No. 1 : End
        } else {
            exit();
        }
    }
    public void highorlow()
    {
        if(usernumber == computernumber)
        {
            System.out.println("Good Job! Your guessed the correct number!"); // Checks if you guessed the correct number
            guesses = guesses +1; // Adds 1 to guess count
        }
        else
        {
            if(usernumber > computernumber) // Checks if your number is higher than the computers
            {
                System.out.println("Your guessed to high please try again");
                guesses =guesses +1; // Adds 1 to guess count

                //Change Code : Change No. 7 : Because we added userguess in the loop
                //userguess(); // Lets user guess again

            }
            else
            {
                if(usernumber < computernumber) // Checks if your number is less than the computers number
                {
                    System.out.println("Your guess was to low please try again");
                    guesses = guesses +1;// Adds 1 to guess count

                    //Change Code : Change No. 7 : Because we added userguess in the loop
                    //userguess(); // Lets user guess again

                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void instructions() // Gives instructions on how to play
    {
        System.out.println("To play simply guess a number between 1 and 100. \nThe computer will tell you if you are correct or inncorrect. \n Press y to continue \n Press e at any time to exit");
        play = scan.next().charAt(0);
    }
    public void printscore()
    {
        System.out.println("Your took "+guesses+" guesses to get the correct number \n"); // Tells user how many guesses they took
    }
    public void replay() // lets user replay game
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Y for yes N for no");
        playagain = scan.next().charAt(0);
        if(playagain =='y')
        {
            replay = true;
            guesses = 0; // If you play again guesses will become zero
            play();
        }
        //Change Code : Change No. 2 : Start
        else {
            replay = false; // Only In case of Y it will continue
        }
        //Change Code : Change No. 2 : End
    }
    public void exit()
    {
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing! The number was "+computernumber+"");
        //Change Code : Change No. 3 : Start
        System.exit(3); // Whenever exit will be called user will be moved out of the application
        //Change Code : Change No. 3 : End
    }
    public void play()
    {
        //Change Code : Change No. 5 : Start
        /*instructions();
        computerguess();
        userguess();
        printscore();
        replay();*/
        //Change Code : Change No. 5 : End [Here we do not require this code if we make replay by default true]
        if(replay == true)
        {
            instructions();
            computerguess();
            //Change Code : Change No. 6 : Start - User must be given multiple guesses
            while(true) {
                userguess();
                highorlow();
                if(usernumber == computernumber) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            //Change Code : Change No. 6 : End
            printscore();
            replay();
        }
        else
        {
            if(replay == false)
            {
                System.exit(3);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Hilo guess = new Hilo();
        guess.play();
    }
}
```